# Plucking segment from VS Code path variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to write a snippet variable transform which will pluck a particular segment out of the path provided by `TM_FILEPATH`.

`TM_FILEPATH`: `~/Projects/folder/Dir/tests/Unit/FooTest.php`

I need to grab `Dir`. I'm trying to use the following regex: `\/([^\/]*)\/tests`.

VS Code snippet transform:

`${TM_FILEPATH/\\/([^\\/]*)\\/tests/$1/}`

Actual output:

`~/Projects/folderDir/Unit/FooTest.php`

It seems that the transform is dropping the value of the full match, rather than replacing the variable with the first matching group, which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"${TM_FILEPATH/.*\\/([^\\/]*)\\/tests.*/$1/}",
```

All I did was add a `.*` before and after your regex.

The **KEY POINT**:  For snippet transforms, if part of the variable is not included in the part to be transformed, it won't be transformed and so ends up in the final result.

```
${TM_FILEPATH/...part to be transformed.../$1/}
```

So your regex was good, just most of the variable was not "signalled" to be transformed and so wasn't.